# Create android external jar as library, no find resources

Tags: java, android, jar

I got a problem when I tried to do this:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chat_list_container);
```

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001

This is a code from external jar I have just created and added to my application.

By the way this exact code working when I used it as import module and not use it like external jar.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You are packaging resources also in the jar? You should make one a library project and reference the same in another if that is the case

Comment: Yes I think I add the resources, how can I be sure about it? In the jar I can see the R file with some content about the ids of the extrnal resources. I made it as library and reference..

Comment: You cannot package resources into jar.

Answer (score 0):

Android will not look for resources in any external jar because they are expected to contains just executable code.

If you want to publish resources as library as well, things gets more ugly. In this case, you could create a resource apk just like framework-res.apk. To do that, create an android project with no source, place the res files and add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
<application
    ...
    android:hasCode=false >
    ...
</application>
```

In this case, you will have to retrieve the res id directly from the res-apk:

```
int resId = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication("res.apk.package.name")
.getIdentifier("chat_list_container" , "layout", "res.apk.package.name");

// Maybe getResources.getIdentifier() works, but I'm not sure.
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(resId);
```

I should mention that the device which will run the application must also has the resource apk installed.

Comment: So, do you mean I can't display a dialog for example,  with some layout easily? That's wierd..

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Realize that android library projects - that one which you set as library in project properties - actually is completely added (source and resources) to the main projects which use them. This is the difference between use an external jar file and set a project as library.